# Reducing duplicate data in vertex buffers

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

I am using 3 vertex buffers at one time (I actually have many, but there are only 3 used at once).

They contain information which is mixed together in a shader to produce the desired output -- a 2D skeletal animation.

There are two *bone* buffers, which contain the position/rotation/scale for a bone at any given frame.

There is one *skin* buffer, which contains the vertices for rendering a region of a texture as if it were at the world origin, *(0,0)*.

In the shader, the two bone buffers are combined with an easing value (passed through as a uniform), and then by transforming the skin vertices, the parts are rendered in the correct places.

This performs great, and is a good improvement on where I started out -- I calculated everything on the GPU, and just passed in x/y/u/v coordinates, I was limited by streaming so much data to the GPU each frame.

However, there's a lot of duplicated information. The skin buffer contains only what it needs, 4 vertices per skin part, each unique.

When it gets combined with the bone though, each bone vertex is duplicated 4 times -- to match the skin buffer. Working on mobile, this is a pain in the nuts, because I'm running low on memory, and it annoys me that there's so much wastage.

This is how the buffers would look if there were just 1 bone.

**Bone buffer 1**

`[x1,y1,rot1] [x1,y1,rot1] [x1,y1,rot1] [x1,y1,rot1]`

**Bone buffer 2**

`[x2,y2,rot2] [x2,y2,rot2] [x2,y2,rot2] [x2,y2,rot2]`

**Skin buffer**

`[xA,yA,uA,vA] [xB,yB,uB,vB] [xC,yC,uC,vC] [xD,yD,uD,vD]`

I won't post the full shader, because there's too much extra stuff going on in there (rotation and scale work similarly):

```
attribute vec2 bonePosition1; // x1, y1
attribute vec2 bonePosition2; // x2, y2
attribute vec2 skinPosition; // xA (or xB .. ), yA (or yB .. )
uniform float a; // Some value 0..1 depending on time
...
vec2 bonePosition = mix(bonePosition1, bonePosition2, a);
vec2 combinedPosition = skinPosition * bonePosition;
```

Note; since I'm targeting iOS primarily (others too, but it's the most restrictive), I know I'm limited to 16 attributes.

Is there some way to shrink down the memory footprint of the bone buffers? I have many, many frames to one skin buffer.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you need to bind more than one indices buffers (`GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`) for buffers with data (`GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`). If you were able to bind 2 `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` buffers may be you can bind a separate `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` too. I don't know if this can be implemented in OpenGL ES. If this is impossible, you can try to save memory by using integers instead of floats but I believe this is not applicable for bones translation/rotation values.

Regarding your note. To overcome the 16 attributes limit, you can combine smaller `vec2` attributes into `vec4`. For example, you can combine `bonePosition1` and `bonePosition2` into one `vec4`:

```
attribute vec4 bonePosition12;
```

And then use it this way in shader:

```
vec2 bonePosition1 = vec2(bonePosition12.x,bonePosition12.y);
vec2 bonePosition2 = vec2(bonePosition12.z,bonePosition12.w);
```

This might have some minor impact on performance, but since this code is in vertex shader performance drop should be negligible, compared with math of shader. I've used similar code to manipulate colors (in fragment shader) and performance is OK.

Comment: I'm already reducing the precision on the bone buffers, so each vertex is actually only 12 bytes (xy into one integer, scale into an integer, rotation as a float).

I'm not quite sure what you mean by binding two `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`s, I've never heard of that. It'd be two separate draw calls right? Or are you saying one `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` for the bone vertices, and one for the skin vertices? That would indeed fix it, but as far as I know, isn't possible. If it is, could you show me?

Comment: @Sticky I mean 2 `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`s. Unfortunately, this can't be done with OpenGL ES 2.0. So the best I can propose is to reduce precision because I understand that combining bones and skins buffers is not an option and cannot be used in your scenario. At least I hope you will resolve your issue with reaching 16 attributes limit.

Comment: Alright well, thanks for the help anyway! I didn't mention the precision changes I'd already done in the question because mostly this was just looking for a way to reduce the amount of stuff that's duplicated. Cheers